# Looking for minimum between a range of index in a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, range, minimum

I am looking for minimum between a range of index in a dictionary; for instance:

```
A = {1: -3, 2: -5, 3: 4, 5: 12, -34: 23, 64: 32}
```

I want to find:

```
min(A[2..5]) = min(A[2] A[3] A[4]A [5]) = -5
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you didn't even googled it. here is a link to [python built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). use it well

Comment: @SaNa, I edited your question to fix syntax errors; hope that's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `list` does not support indexing via a list of indexers. There are a couple of solutions to overcome this.

#### Where you know keys exist

You can use `itemgetter` and sequence unpacking:

```
from operator import itemgetter

A = {1: -3, 2: -5, 3: 4, 5: 12, -34: 23, 64: 32}

res = min(itemgetter(*[2, 3, 5])(A))

# -5
```

#### Where keys may not exist

You can use a `range` object to specify a range of keys. A `list` or `set` would work too. Here we feed a generator expression to `min`:

```
res = min(v for k, v in A.items() if k in range(2, 6))

# -5
```